# <Item> used in java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading some code and want to understand why the following would work:

This is a Stack class:  `public class Stack<Item> { ***** }`

Then in the main method an instance of the class has been created:
`Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();`

What exactly does the `Item` mean in the Generic Stack class declaration? Is it the standard Java `Item` class, or is it a naming convention of Java generics? I would think that `String` needs to be a subclass of this `Item` in order for the code to work, right?

Comment: Where is "Item" in you code ?

Comment: What is a java item class?

Comment: Where in what code do you see the `public class Stack<Item>` declaration?

Comment: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Stack.java.html

Comment: To everyone asking where do they see this code:  Have you refreshed your page yet?

Comment: It will compile and run.

Comment: You'll want to look [at this Java Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html) to get you started.  I don't normally see longer-winded generic type definitions unless they actually *mean* something; here `Item` conveys no extra meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
public class Stack<Item>
```

`Item` is a **formal** type parameter name.  It doesn't correspond to any particular java class, so there's no implied package name for it.

In

```
Stack<MyItem> stack = new Stack<MyItem>();
```

`MyItem` is an **actual** binding for a type `Item`, so must correspond to an actual class and has an implicit package.

The difference between ["formal" and "actual" parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29#Parameters_and_arguments) is the same as the difference between `x` and `42` below:

```
int f(int x) { ... }   // x is a formal parameter name

System.out.println(f(42));   // 42 is the actual parameter to which the formal x is bound.
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - this makes a lot of sense. So from a java syntax point of view, I can use any name to replace item, right? for example, I could use "thing", "stuff", etc as the name of the formal type parameter and the same code will compile and work?

Comment: @user2210021, yep.  You could replace `x` in the body of `f` with a different name and it would work as well, and you can replace `Item` with any Java identifier as long as you consistently replace uses of it in the body of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`Item` does not seem to be a standard Java class. It may be just an arbitrary generic type in which case the specific `String` type can be used without any issues.

Are you referring to this implementation of a Stack class ?

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Stack.java.html

> I would think that String needs to be a subclass of this Item in order for the code to work, right?

Not necessarily. Go through the Java trail given in the comments above. It is possible to define generics such that you can "slot in" a class and use the generic type to refer to it throughout a class or method.

P.S: Note that generics are only enforced during compile time. They don't exist in the bytecode.

Comment: Thanks - so I can use any arbitrary name as the formal type parameter?

Comment: Dare to try. You can only gain more experience :)